# F# STA Thread Async

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, f#

I call this this function from the GUI thread:

```
let updateImageLoop (pprocess : PlotProcess) (target : IUpdatableImageView<'T>) =
    async {
      while target.Continue do
        let context = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current
        do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
        do! Async.SwitchToContext(context)
        let image = target.CreateImage()
        match image with
        | Some userImage -> do! target.UpdateImageView userImage 
        | None -> ()
    } |> Async.StartImmediate
```

The problem comes when the method **target.UpdateImageView** is executed, an exception is generated:

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

I know that, but that is what i did with

```
do! Async.SwitchToContext(context)
```

Eliminating the functions SwitchToContext and SwitchToThreadPool, removes the exception, but the GUI just freezes. And that makes sense, but why i can't make the switch between threads??

The function that generates the problem is UpdateImageView. I tested it with and without making it async.

```
member this.UpdateImageView  etoimage =
  async {
    let imageview = new Eto.Forms.ImageView()
    imageview.Image <- etoimage
    this.Content <- imageview
  }
```

edit ---

```
Testing with this code:
let updateImageLoop (pprocess : PlotProcess) (target : IUpdatableImageView<'T>) =
    let context = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current
    let printThread text =
        printfn "[%d] %s" System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId text
    async {
      while target.Continue do
        printThread "begining"
        do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()
        printThread "after swith to thread pool"
        let image = target.CreateImage()
        match image with
        | Some userImage -> 
            printThread "before switch to context"
            do! Async.SwitchToContext context 
            printThread "after switch to context"
            target.UpdateImageView userImage 
        | None -> ()
    } |> Async.StartImmediate
```

Prints :

```
[1] begining 
[4] after swith to thread pool 
[4] before switch to context 
[5] after switch to context
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `[<STAThread>]` attribute to your assembly?

Comment: My main function start with; [<EntryPoint;STAThread>] let main args = ...

Comment: If the exception is being thrown by `UpdateImageView`, perhaps it is expecting to be called on the same STA thread that created the image? That is, perhaps the library you are using expects `CreateImage` and `UpdateImageView` to be called on the same thread.

Comment: I noticed that  System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current is always null in the main thread. I'm searching how to fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use [< STAThread >]
2. Use the guiContext to work on the GUI

In your GUI creation (framework init) remember the guiContext

```
let guiContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current
```

and pass it into async GUI execute

```
// the async GUI execute 
async {
            let currentContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current 
            do! Async.SwitchToContext(guiContext)
            f() // work on the GUI
            do! Async.SwitchToContext(currentContext)   
}
```

Put the waiting in an extra step to keep it composable.

Comment: And in my personal case, the call to System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current  need to be after the first window is shown.